# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type of Model but this dictionary type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have built an MVC 5 application that is pulling a list of categories from the DB to help me build my main nav elements.

```
@Html.Partial("_NavigationPartial")
```

If I add new List to the partial helper it then kills all of the nav on the site.

```
@Html.Partial("_NavigationPartial", new List<Category>)
```

Once a user clicks on the Nav element it takes them to a details page of that particular category and it throws the Dictionary error. All of my views are strongly typed and I don't understand what I need to pass so it renders correctly. My details page is typed to Models.Category while my partial view is modeled to IEnumerable

Comment: what is the @model type in _NavigationPartial?

Comment: IEnumerable<Category> Sorry, I somehow something...

Comment: What do you mean _kills all of the nav on the site_? If you pass an empty collection to the partial, then there will be no categories to display? The error your getting is not related to the code you have shown - it relates to whats happening when you click on a nav element - you need to show the code for that.

Comment: Does this help: 

@Html.Partial("_NavigationPartial", new List<Category> () )

Comment: here is my partial:
'@model IEnumerable<mvcproject.Models.Category>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @foreach (var category in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(category.catname, "Details", "Categories", new { area = "", id = category.categoryID }, null)</li>
    }
</ul>'

Comment: @Woundedbear, you need to edit your question with the extra code (too hard to read in comments), but if clicking on one of those links generates that error, then its probably because your Details view has `@model IEnumerable<Category>` when it should be `@model Category`